# How to scale KivyMD application

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

[image]I am new to Kivy and unsure of how to scale the screen so that if being viewed on a mobile phone or not in full screen, the application scales down to the correct viewing size.

I have added screenshots of what the application currently looks like in full screen and then what happens when it is made smaller.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks:)

```py
from kivy import Config
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior
from kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer import MDNavigationLayout, MDNavigationDrawer
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList, OneLineAvatarListItem, ILeftBody
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,disable_multitouch')


class DrawerList(ThemableBehavior, MDList, Screen):
    pass


class NavLayout(MDNavigationLayout):
    pass


class Login(Screen):
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


class Nav(Screen):
    Login = ObjectProperty()
    ScreenManager = ObjectProperty


class Homepage(Screen):
    Login = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


class AddNewCustomer(Screen):
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


class AddNewStaff(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    Login = ObjectProperty()


class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        # Window.maximize()
        # self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        # self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "900"
        login = Builder.load_file("login.kv")
        return login


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

```
ScreenManager:
    Login:
    Homepage:
    AddNewCustomer:
    Nav:
    DrawerList:

<Login>:
    name: "login"
    MDCard:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 700, 800
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        elevation: 10
        padding: 25
        spacing: 25
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Image:
            source: 'images/asteria.png'
            size: 100, 200

        MDLabel:
            id: login
            font_size: 40
            halign: 'center'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            padding_y: 15

        MDTextFieldRound:
            id: user
            hint_text: "username"
            icon_right: "account"
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 200
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}

        MDTextFieldRound:
            id: password
            hint_text: "password"
            icon_right: "eye-off"
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 200
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
            password: True

        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: "LOGIN"
            font_size: 12
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}

            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "homepage"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: "CLEAR"
            font_size: 12
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
            on_press: app.clear()


        Widget:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50


<Nav>:
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Add New Customer"

                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "addNewCustomer"
                    root.screen_manager.transition.direction = "right"





            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Add New Staff"
                font_size: 15
                halign: "center"
                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "addNewStaff"

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Case List"
                font_size: 15
                halign: "center"
                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "caseList"


            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Create Case"
                font_size: 15
                halign: "center"
                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.transition.direction = "left"
                    root.screen_manager.current = "Create Case"


            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Log Out"
                font_size: 15
                halign: "center"
                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")

                    root.manager.current = "login"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "right"



<Homepage>:
    name: "homepage"
    Screen:

        MDNavigationLayout:
            ScreenManager:
                id: screen_manager
                Screen:
                    name: "Homepage"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Welcome Home"
                        halign: "center"


                Screen:
                    name: "addNewCustomer"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Add New customer"
                        halign: "center"

                Screen:
                    name: "addNewStaff"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Add New Staff"
                        halign: "center"

                Screen:
                    name: "caseList"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case List"
                        halign: "center"

                Screen:
                    name: "casePool"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case Pool"
                        halign: "center"

                Screen:
                    name: "Create Case"


                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Case Title"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.875, "center_x": 0.115}



                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: CaseTitle
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        icon_right: "Case Title"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 15
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.863, "center_x": 0.155}


                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Customer"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.791, "center_x": 0.115}



                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Customer
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        icon_right: "Customer"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 14
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.779, "center_x": 0.155}


                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Customer Forename"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        multiline: False
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.707, "center_x": 0.115}


                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Customer Forename
                        hint_text: "Info here"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        icon_right: "Customer"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 137.5
                        font_size: 14
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.687, "center_x": 0.121}

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Customer Surname"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        multiline: False
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.707, "center_x": 0.210}


                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Customer Forename
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        icon_right: "Customer"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 137.5
                        font_size: 14
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.687, "center_x": 0.210}

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Alternative email"
                        font_size: 15
                        size_hint_x: None
                        multiline: False
                        bold: True
                        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.620, "center_x": 0.115}


                    MDTextFieldRound:
                        id: Alternative email
                        hint_text: "Info Here"
                        mode:"rectangle"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 275
                        font_size: 15
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.600, "center_x": 0.155}



        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            MDToolbar:
                title: 'Navigation'
                left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state('open')]]
                right_action_items: [["images/asteria.png", lambda x: None]]


                elevation:5
            Widget:


        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            Nav:
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer
                manager: root.manager
```

Comment: I don't see any screenshots of the app here. Also, I tried the app and it seems to scale evenly.

Comment: Hi - I added the screenshot of what the app looks like in half screen. As you can see the text fields haven't scaled properly.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the widgets' x position is already low (the widgets are already to the left). Just increase this value and it should look better:

```
Screen:
    name: "Create Case"


    MDLabel:
        text: "Case Title"
        font_size: 15
        size_hint_x: None
        bold: True
        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.875, "center_x": 0.415}



    MDTextFieldRound:
        id: CaseTitle
        hint_text: "Info Here"
        icon_right: "Case Title"
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 275
        font_size: 15
        pos_hint: {"top": 0.863, "center_x": 0.455}



    MDLabel:
        text: "Customer"
        font_size: 15
        size_hint_x: None
        bold: True
        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.791, "center_x": 0.415}



    MDTextFieldRound:
        id: Customer
        hint_text: "Info Here"
        mode:"rectangle"
        icon_right: "Customer"
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 275
        font_size: 14
        pos_hint: {"top": 0.779, "center_x": 0.455}


    MDLabel:
        text: "Customer Forename"
        font_size: 15
        size_hint_x: None
        multiline: False
        bold: True
        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.707, "center_x": 0.315}


    MDTextFieldRound:
        id: Customer Forename
        hint_text: "Info here"
        mode:"rectangle"
        icon_right: "Customer"
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 137.5
        font_size: 14
        pos_hint: {"top": 0.687, "center_x": 0.321}

    MDLabel:
        text: "Customer Surname"
        font_size: 15
        size_hint_x: None
        multiline: False
        bold: True
        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.707, "center_x": 0.710}


    MDTextFieldRound:
        id: Customer Forename
        hint_text: "Info Here"
        mode:"rectangle"
        icon_right: "Customer"
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 137.5
        font_size: 14
        pos_hint: {"top": 0.687, "center_x": 0.710}

    MDLabel:
        text: "Alternative email"
        font_size: 15
        size_hint_x: None
        multiline: False
        bold: True
        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.620, "center_x": 0.415}


    MDTextFieldRound:
        id: Alternative Email
        hint_text: "Info Here"
        mode:"rectangle"
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 275
        font_size: 15
        pos_hint: {"top": 0.600, "center_x": 0.455}

    MDLabel:
        text: "Alternative Phone"
        font_size: 15
        size_hint_x: None
        multiline: False
        bold: True
        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.533, "center_x": 0.415}


    MDTextFieldRound:
        id: Alternative phone
        hint_text: "Info Here"
        mode:"rectangle"
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 275
        font_size: 15
        pos_hint: {"top": 0.513, "center_x": 0.455}



    MDLabel:
        text: "Case Source"
        font_size: 15
        size_hint_x: None
        multiline: False
        bold: True
        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.449, "center_x": 0.415}

    MDTextFieldRound:
        id: Case Source
        hint_text: "Info Here"
        mode:"rectangle"
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 275
        font_size: 15
        pos_hint: {"top": 0.437, "center_x": 0.455}


    MDLabel:
        text: "Case Source"
        font_size: 15
        size_hint_x: None
        multiline: False
        bold: True
        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.449, "center_x": 0.415}

    MDTextFieldRound:
        id: Case Source
        hint_text: "Info Here"
        mode:"rectangle"
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 275
        font_size: 15
        pos_hint: {"top": 0.437, "center_x": 0.455}

    MDLabel:
        text: "Case Priority"
        font_size: 15
        size_hint_x: None
        multiline: False
        bold: True
        color: 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 1
        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.365, "center_x": 0.415}

    MDTextFieldRound:
        id: Case Priority
        hint_text: "Info Here"
        mode:"rectangle"
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 275
        font_size: 15
        pos_hint: {"top": 0.353, "center_x": 0.455}
```

Screen at full width:
[image: Screen at full width]
Screen at 1/2 width:
[image: Screen at 1/2 width]

You can mess around with the `pos_hint` to make it look a bit neater.